# unzip script unix

Tags: unix

I am a new user to unix that is trying to do a simple script in bash that will unzip several files in the location that I list.  I can't figure out why it keeps crashing.  I'm inserting the script below.  I hope to later move the old .tar.7z zipped files into another directory (hence my creating the new directory in the script below), but I am just trying to get the main part working first.

```
#!~/bash
# My program to try to unzip several files with ending of tar.7z
# I have inserted the ability to enter the directory where you want this to be done 

echo "What file location is required for unzipping?"

read dirloc

cd $dirloc
mkdir oldzippedfiles
for directory in $dirloc
        do
                if
                [ $directory=*.tar.7z ]
                then
                cat $directory | 7za x -an -txz -si -so | tar -xf -
        fi
        done

echo "unzipping of file is complete"

exit 0
```

Comment: What do you mean by crashing? You have a wrong [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) is that a typo? What error are you getting? Are you on Unix or Linux? If Linux, which Linux? Why are you using `cat`? Could you give an example of a directory you want to run this script on?

Comment: Sorry, I am on a linux machine.  When I mentioned that it was crashing, the terminal window shut down.  I was using the cat command to read the contents of the file.  So, this leads me to the obvious thing I was doing wrong and that was directory (above) should be replaced with filename  - sorry to be so unclear, but I've gotten the script to run.  Thanks

Comment: How did you get it to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of errors in your script:

1. `#!~/bash` won't work since it's bash that expands `~` to your home directory. You have to specify the full path to bash (usually `/bin/bash`).
2. `for directory in $dirloc` won't work because of two reasons:

   - To go through the files inside `$dirloc`, you'd need `$dirloc/*`.
   - You already changed directories, so it has to be plain `*`.

   Also, since you're looping through files, I suggest renaming your variable.
3. test (`[`) doesn't support glob matching.

   Use `for file in *.tar.7z` instead.
4. There is no need to use cat. It makes things more difficult, since 7zip can't *guess* the archive format from the extension. `-txz` won't work, unless you actually created an `.xz` file fith a `.7z` extension (bad practice).

   Use `7za a -so $directory` instead.
5. I'm not sure what the `-an` switch is supposed to do, but it throws errors and I'm pretty certain it's not needed.

A working version of your script should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

read dirloc

cd $dirloc

for file in *.tar.7z
        do
                7za x -so $file | tar -xf -
        done
```

Comment: This is barely legible as a comment. You can post your corrected approach as an answer if it is working.